Why is my angular datetimepicker adding increment/decrement text over arrows on input?
I can't figure out why my datetimepicker in my angular project is suddenly adding these weird lines of text over my arrows on the time input. They appear to be related to increment/decrement hours/mins as I see in the code itself and when I remove them everything is fine, but i'm not sure how they are being added in the first place. Please help!




You have entered a text between <span> </span>. Span usually used as inline container used to mark up a part of a text. If you don't have code or styles that supress the content inside this block, then that's why you see on the screen everything what you typed in.
If you have another place that worked with a text between <span> ...</span>, you can share the implementation and might hear some suggestion or advice.
P.S. Do not insert code examples as picture.
